# Discharge of capacitor bellow 0.5V

Tags: capacitor, 555, delay

I have a conundrum that I am trying to solve and am afraid I am stuck. Could anyone share some insight please?  [image: snapshot of circuit]

My circuit is displayed on image above. 5V (5Vsw) and 3.3V (3V3sw) are used as supply voltages. When Vkill is triggered, entire circuit switches off. However, depending on start of new power cycle, time delay brought on by 555, varies on case to case basis.

This is seen in plot from circuit.[image: Plot of voltages of interest]

Vkill is business end of sub-circuit, which turns off entire circuit and Vprob is voltage that is giving me headache. Ven is control voltage given by other part of circuit (not shown here) and Vbatt is power for entire circuit.

My first attempt was to add a bleed transistor that drains some (if not all) of the excess energy, but this is still not enough, because of diode drop on mosfet conduction. Time variation is dampened but not eliminated.

Can anyone give me an example on how to dump ALL energy from capacitor bank (C5,C6,C7) as soon as Vkill is triggered? 
Suggestions to changing timer circuit to solve the issue and far fetched ideas are also welcome.

Thanks for all useful suggestions.

Comment: You have a lot of capacitance to drain there. A different approach: you could add a counter and run the 555 at a higher frequency. The error would be much, much smaller.

Comment: The DIS (pin 7) of a 555 chip is the **discharge output**, it is connected to the collector of an NPN to ground. So this is an **output**. I do not see how this can be used as an input to start this circuit.

Comment: This is a quick-glance thing but... are you trying to make a monostable here? It doesn't look connected up properly, I think your output should be taken from OUT and DISCH used to discharge your capacitors... Please edit your question and describe detail what your application requires, not the circuit you have made. Thanks :-)

Comment: *because of diode drop on mosfet conduction* How? If you make a MOSFET fully conduct (which your schematic can do if Vbatt is high enough) then there should be no voltage drop. If you have a diode voltage drop when using a MOSFET, you're using it wrong. Hmm, the AO6407 is a PMOS but you need to use an NMOS!!!! -1 for a poorly designed circuit.

Comment: What circuit does VKill go to? Can you use OUT (pin 3) to kill the power instead of DIS, then use DIS to discharge the capacitors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to familiarize yourself with the internals of a 555: -

[image]

So when you say: -

> Vkill is business end of sub-circuit, which turns off entire circuit

How do you rationalize this when clearly (in the picture above) the discharge pin is an output and you are trying to drive it with Vkill?

The Discharge pin is used to discharge capacitors. The internal NPN transistor will discharge them down to a few milli volts in a fairly short time but ignoring the strange idea of trying to drive the discharge pin, if you want to discharge those capacitors from an external circuit then use an N channel MOSFET with source to ground and hit the gate with a positive voltage to discharge those capacitors.

Trying to discharge capacitors with a P channel source follower will leave several hundred mV across them.

Comment: I understand your explanation. 
Discharge pin usage was "given from somebody with higher rank" that this discharge pin should be used for this configuration. My original idea was to use output pin as output. Thanks for setting me right.

I haven´t displayed entire circuit schematic. This part of circuit (sub circuit) is just for turn off, and then this turns off entire circuit (not shown here).

Comment: I can't really respond with any more advice.